# getting all the instances of a model into an oblect

Tags: python, django

I have a model called sickness, which I have used to create multiple instances like malaria, typhoid, and others.

model

```
class Sickness(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

please, how can I get this into a dictionary form like this where the name will be gotten into the dictionary.

```
duration_choices = {
    'malaria':'malaria',
    'typhod':'typhod',
    'cough':'cough',
    'headache':'headache',
    'stomach gas':'stomach gas',
}
```

so, assuming I have created numerous sicknesses in my db like this:

[image]

that will be contained in the dictionary, and if others are added later, they will be contained in the dictionary when it is called for

Comment: can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @kalzso I added more context

Comment: What use do you have for a dictionary where every key also is its value? Are you sure you are not looking for a simple `list` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you want the keys and values in the dictionary to be the same value, but you could achieve what you want with:

```py
duration_choices = {i.name: i.name for i in Sickness.objects.all()}
```